# MySQL: Could I use UPPER() and TRIM() at the same time?

Tags: mysql

Because there are '-' in front of every string in every row, I wanna remove them and make every string data upper at the same time.
I tried the script below, but it didn't work. The ‘-‘ still existed.

My script:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(LEADING '-' FROM UPPER(breed)) AS 'upper_breed'
FROM dogs
ORDER BY breed;
```

Thanks

Comment: There's no reference to the "*breed*" field in your `SELECT` statement. Change the `ORDER BY` clause like this: `ORDER BY 'upper_breed'`

Comment: *I tried the script below, but it didn't work.* What do you mean? does not sort correctly? produces an error? something else?

Comment: here's the error https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5e14caf4b3454882a9dd0498c259397f and the solution @akina

Comment: @lemon You're correct. The column of the source table can be used in ORDER BY even when it is not listed in output list. Of course when there is no either GROUP BY or ambiguity. I miss that DISTINCT (which is GROUP BY analog) is used. Sorry...

Comment: just a heads up to any future readers.  P.Salmon code is intended not to work (as far as I understand anyway) . to make it work change  order by  to upper_breed and it will be okay

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: if your actual problem is: "The ‘-‘ still existed" then check for leading spaces in the column `breed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is within the `ORDER BY` clause: there's no "*breed*" column in your `SELECT` clause. You should rather use "*upper_breed*":

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM(LEADING '-' FROM UPPER(breed)) AS 'upper_breed'
FROM dogs
ORDER BY 'upper_breed';
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8T9sHQHZUT1na7Zyn7Q74J/0).

Note: avoid using quotes for column names, or if you want to, use backticks (like `upper_breed`).